# Create MongoDB field with a values from populated document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a users collection and Companies collection. Right now the output looks like this:

```
"_id":"5ce543a5390d87567f523153",
"updatedAt":"2019-10-18T15:01:53.812Z",
"createdAt":"2019-05-22T12:42:13.046Z",
"associatedCompany":{
                 "_id":"5ce543a4390d87567f523148",
                 "companyName":"Company Two"},
"accountStatus":1,
"roleInfo":{"roleType":1},
"role":2,
"personalInfo":{    
 "fullName":"SomeName",
         "firstName":"Name",
          "lastName":"Last",
           "email":"email@email.com",
          "phone":{"countryCode":"SE","number":"9876543210"}}}
```

Where company field is populated from Company collection.

Is there a way to display just a company name right away with firstName and lastName field without "personalInfo" field so the output will look like:

```
{"data":[{
"_id":"5ce543a5390d87567f523153",
"updatedAt":"2019-10-18T15:01:53.812Z",
"createdAt":"2019-05-22T12:42:13.046Z",
 "companyName":"Company Two",
"accountStatus":1,
"roleInfo":{"roleType":1},
"role":2,
"firstName":"Name",
"lastName":"Last",
"email":"email@email.com"
```

Query I am using

```
  const listUsers = (skip, limit = 10) => {
    let config = {
      populate: {
          'path': 'associatedCompany',
          'select': 'companyName'
        },
        limit: Number(limit),
        skip: Number(skip),
      };
```

I have tried to do it with aggregation and lookup but without success.
Thanks is advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use projection to filter the fields that you want to be displayed in your output.

Refer:
[mongoDB projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/)